# print_r function in php not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

My Code

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM manifest WHERE (awb_no = '$var')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $_SESSION['arr1'] = $row; 
    }
    print_r($_SESSION['arr1']);
```

When I print `$_session` recursively it is printing the values obtained twice and the output looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 201505151312 
    [document_no] => 201505151312 
    [1] => FMPC1658606996 
    [awb_no] => FMPC1658606996 
    [2] => OD3028479929633865304 
    [order_id] => OD3028479929633865304 
    [3] => [forms] => 
    [4] => [extras] => 
)
```

As you can see the document number field,awb_no field etc are all printing twice. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Use `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: As above, this is expected behavior of `mysql_fetch_array` Also, obligitory **DONT US mysql_* functions**

Comment: You are returning BOTH the numerated array and the associative array. If you only want one, specify that in the way described in the manual, or use (for instance) mysql_fetch_assoc(). But all of this is irrelevant because you shouldn't be using PHP's deprecated mysql API. See mysqli_ or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`mysql_fetch_assoc` solve your problem

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM manifest WHERE (awb_no = '$var')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $_SESSION['arr1'] = $row;
}
print_r($_SESSION['arr1']);
```

> **Note : This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0**

Comment: Yes please pay attention to the bold blockquote

Comment: But what purpose does the deprecation quote serve here? You're still encouraging OP to keep using it, didn't even hint at the interpolated variable, or offer an alternative.